# Eclipse MAT shows memory leak due to Volley NetworkDispatcher and CacheDispatcher

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-volley, eclipse-memory-analyzer

[image: This is excluding weak references]

I'm new to MAT and how to detect and remove leaks, but why is volley behind all my leaks?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i wasn't using a Singleton Pattern for my RequestQueues
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton
This link solved my problem

Also @Turnsole 's advice is solid, will be sure to cancel requests when I don't need them anymore

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue when running automated tests that would repeatedly background/resurface the application. My solution (which resolved the problem for running tests at least) was to do this in the tearDown():

```
    // cancel() for each request will get them removed, which can otherwise leak memory
    MyApplication.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Depending on how your request queue is being managed, you could do something similar. The problem is that when the queue gets stopped, requests are left in the queue and never cleaned up. So anywhere you're starting/stopping the queue, you need to take extra care to cancel any outstanding requests.

Comment: Yes absolutely correct i should cancel my Requests.
The problem was however that i should use a Singleton Pattern.
I will apply your advice too also thanks a lot

Comment: Aha, yes, that would also cause this problem to be visible.

Comment: if you have any idea of how to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964271/android-volley-singleton-pattern-how-to-add-cancel-requests-based-on-tag so i can cancel my requests