# Android Volley Singleton Pattern how to add/cancel requests based on tag

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-volley

According to https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton 
it is discouraged to use the old way of implementing a singleton class by setting up the RequestQueue in Application.onCreate()

The provided "new" more modular way as seen below however doesn't contain a method for adding tags to requests and cancelling them using these tags.

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

How do I go about adding the methods similar to the ones below from the old way (in Application.onCreate()):

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing about RequestQueue has changed in that respect. You're just accessing it from a different singleton than the Application class. Add the tags to the requests the same way you always would:

```
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(...);
request.setTag(MY_TAG);
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

-- edit --

Further elaboration: it's the same as if you were to get the RequestQueue object from anywhere else. It's still just a RequestQueue.

So this:

```
mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
```

Becomes:

```
MySingleton.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);
```

The same goes for anything else you were previously doing with a RequestQueue. The example MySingleton class there is just acting to hold on to the request queue for you. It isn't changing it.

To cancel absolutely everything, no matter what tag:

```
MySingleton.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: there's no examples about removing a all requests with a specific tag, there aren't even any examples about removing requests

Comment: If you want to add more convenience methods to the MySingleton class, just look at the addToRequestQueue(...) method that's already there in the example code. All you have to do is write the convenience method and perform whatever action on the RequestQueue object that MySingleton owns.

Comment: @Turnsole hello, I'm having memory leaks with anonymous classes in volley specifically the callback listeners function and then I read about "cancelALL". Where exactly do I put the "MySingleton.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);" is it in the activity right after the "MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);" ?

Comment: You would call cancelAll(...) whenever you can safely assume the request is no longer needed. If you do it immediately after adding it to the queue, then it might never be completed. 

Hard to say without seeing your use case but inside onPause() is probably a good choice, assuming that anything the Activity needs to load would get re-loaded in onResume().